# ViewResult Not Rendering Page Content in ASP.NET WebForms Project with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms APP, I want to migrate it to ASP.NET MVC a piece at a time. I have setup MVC to run within the webforms app. I have everything set up appropriately such that if I put my ASP.NET MVC folders (Controllers, Views) in a subfolder called MVC in the project, and set my routes in my global asax to

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
        "w/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
    );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

All of the config and assembly references are setup.  If I debug I can hit a breakpoint that is inside my Index method, on my Home controller.

```
public class HomeController
    : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.HttpContext.Trace.Write("Hrm...");
        return View("index", (object)"Hello");
    }
}
```

The problem that is occurring is that

```
return View("index", (object)"Hello");
```

Does not return an error status code or the search list you'd expect typically if MVC can't locate the view.  Instead I am getting a 200 http response, and nothing in the content body of the response.

Here are the http request details:

```
GET http://localhost.:2396/w/home/index2 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost.:2396
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=3yqf2t55sckemhmxq2bhibmq

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 09 May 2012 12:42:43 GMT
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

That request above goes to index2, which is an action that doesn't exist and it doesn't give me an error.  I suspect the ViewResult in the index action is throwing an exception but somehow it's getting supressed somewhere.  I inherited this code base, so I'm just trying to figure out whats going on.

In the web.config i've configured the error handling such that i should be able to see any errors messages, but that still doesn't explain why the http status code is always 200.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>

<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"/>
```

Another quick note, is if i replace

```
return View("index", (object)"Hello");
```

with

```
return Content("abc");
```

It will correctly output "abc" in the content body of the http response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Quick Q: what if you return View() or return View("index")?

Comment: I just tested again to be sure, but all have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your view is in wrong location because you mentioned that Controller, Views are under a folder called "MVC".

The "Views" folder should be under the root directory, that is the place where ViewEngine looks for the views.

**Update:**
You can override this default behavior using a custom ViewEngine. For that implement `IViewEngine` interface and it has got a method called `FindView` where you can implement your own logic to scan different location.

Comment: true... but it seems like he would get the ysod complaining about not finding the view.

Comment: ha! thanks. I swore I tried this and it didn't fix it before.  But when i relocated them this time it worked.  I'm assuming I can use an area registration to relocate them back into the MVC subfolder.  Just need to do some research into how i set that up.

Comment: @andrew yeah, im not seeing any YSOD's as demonstrated by calling INDEX2. Still haven't figured out why though.

Comment: Actually, just to make it easy i'm going to just make my own View extension method to add the "~/mvc/views/" so i can keep them in the subfolder.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: Great suggestion. I ultimately wrote an override for Controller.View(string, string, object) to preprend the path. This is less elegant than your solution and prevents you from using the shared folders and stuff, but its an easy quick fix.

What i'd really like to see, is the asp.net team, create an abstraction from the view engine, that would be something like an "IViewLocator".